# Parameters are not working in Google Cloud Print using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-print

I need to send print Job to my printer using Google Cloud Print. It is a Classic Printer Named RISO ComColor 7150. My Code in Apps Script is as follows:-

```
  function printGoogleDocument(docID, printerID, docName , type , duplex) {


var ticket = {
version: "1.0",
print: {
  color: {
    type: type,
    vendor_id: "Color"
  },
  duplex: {
    type: duplex
  }
}
};

 var payload = {
"printerid" : printerID,
"title"     : docName,
"content"   : DriveApp.getFileById(docID).getBlob(),
"contentType": "application/pdf",
"ticket"    : JSON.stringify(ticket),
"pages"     : "1,2"
};

 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit', {
method: "POST",
payload: payload,
headers: {
  Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getCloudPrintService().getAccessToken()
},
"muteHttpExceptions": true
});

 response = JSON.parse(response);

 if (response.success) {
Logger.log("%s", response.message);
 } else {
Logger.log("Error Code: %s %s", response.errorCode, response.message);
}
}
```

problem is When i am Sending type to STANDARD_COLOR and duplex to NO_DUPLEX than it is Working fine but when i change them to MONOCHROME and DUPLEX than it is Giving me Color print with no duplex again. Also i am Sending Page Number but it Prints whole pdf instead of giving me print of specific page.

Can Anybody tell me what i am doing worng here??

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: are you using ajax at all in the page view? if so you need to do some "fun stuff"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can set all the things in print job ticket, no need to specify the page number outside ticket.
Here ,a CJT am recommending ,

```
var ticket = "{\"version\":\"1.0\",\"print\":{\"color\":{\"vendor_id\":\"1\",\"type\":1},\"duplex\":{\"type\":0},\"page_orientation\":{\"type\":"0"},\"copies\":{\"copies\": "2"},\"fit_to_page\":{\"type\":3},\"page_range\":{\"interval\":[{\"start\": "1",\"end\":"2"}]},\"media_size\":{\"width_microns\":210000,\"height_microns\":297000,\"is_continuous_feed\":false,\"vendor_id\":\"9\"},\"collate\":{\"collate\":false},\"reverse_order\":{\"reverse_order\":false}}}";
```

so you can specify duplex, page limit..etc

It would be nice if you can go this documentation.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/cdd#pts

And for duplex,its an integer expecting, you can set this way..if  NO_DUPLEX is needed you need to send 0,
    NO_DUPLEX = 0;
    LONG_EDGE = 1;
    SHORT_EDGE = 2;

Comment: it is giving me error when i used this. Saying  Error Code: 424.0 Failed to parse the print job's print ticket. @AhammadaliPK

Comment: Thank you Very Much....This Made My work.....i should have read that one day earlier.....

Comment: Happy to hear .carry on